# Can I use GCM for new play store apps?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging

## My apps

I have a few play store apps that work with GCM, and I am trying to create two new ones in the Play store console.

Google is pushing [FCM, the new cool kid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), that [should replace GCM in the future](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and they have posted the [following notice in the GCM page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/):

[image]

## My problem

I don't want to migrate to FCM now - I don't have the time for the server side mess.

When I try to link a GCM sender ID for the console for the new apps, I can only link FCM sender ids, not GCM.

[image]

## What have I tried

I tried looking for GCM options in the console, but found none.

## My question

**Is GCM permanently blocked for new apps? Are we forced to use FCM with them, or is there a way to link existing GCM sender ids to new apps?**

Comment: What server side mess? Mostly the same as before

Comment: server side changes are very very minimal, all you are changing is to where you send the message to

Comment: @tyczj For each place in my code (which serves more than one app), for each user, I will have to check whether FCM or GCM should be used; in my system, this requires quite a bit of refactoring I hoped I could avoid.

Comment: Have you tried adding the GCM Sender ID? Was there an error? There are instances that even Google Docs refer to GCM as FCM, but its still applicable to GCM. Do try it out.

Comment: @AL.I ran into the same problem. I tried linking a GCM sender id, and got the response 'Invalid FCM API Key (Bad Key).'

Comment: @AdamMatan Did you ever figure this out? Unfortunately we are very tied to GCM at the moment, and would love to know if we can continue using GCM for at least a short period of time.

Comment: @elightbo So far FCM and GCM links and keys work across. No official references, though.

Comment: @AdamMatan Thanks for the help. I was being silly and used the sender id rather than the api key.

Comment: Not your fault. They could provide note useful hints for common errors.